# How to add a dot indicator on a Gridview ? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Is there a way in Flutter to show a dot indicator on Gridview ? or is there a widget like gridview that I can combine it with CarouselSlider ?

Something like this:
[image]

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: You can just put a GridView inside a CarouselSlider itemBuilder.

Comment: could you add any image reference or wireframe so we can get what exactly you want to get?

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far?

Comment: If GridView doesn't work with Carousel Slider try making the grid using rows and columns

Comment: @YeasinSheikh https://pastebin.com/C8NThjkq I tried CarouselSlider with StaggeredGrid.count but I can't scroll the grid

Comment: @BìnhNguyễn could you please provide an example ? thank you

Comment: I think you dont need gridView, decorate item with row/columns and then use CarouselSlider

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I tried CarouselSlider.builder as proposed from Bình Nguyễn but I'm only getting the first 9 items, and when I scroll I also get the same images. Column and row might be a good solution. Still how can I integrate a dote indicator ? Is there a specific widget for it ?

Comment: You can try with [dots_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/dots_indicator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on The Design picture you provided, Instead of a grid view, you actually need a Carousel, or a page, to implement the pagination.

[carousel_builder](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) package or PageView widget is the solution for implementing the pagination.
to achieve the dots indicator, you can use [dots_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/dots_indicator) mentioned in the comments.
then you should use your pageview or carousel controller, and on changing the index, update your indicator.

I'll provide the code of an image_slider I implemented, you can edit and achieve what you want:

```
class ImageSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> urls;
  final bool openImagePopUp;
  final PageController sliderController;
  const ImageSlider(
      {Key key, this.urls, this.openImagePopUp = false, this.sliderController})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ImageSliderState createState() => _ImageSliderState();
}

class _ImageSliderState extends State<ImageSlider> {
  int currentSlideIndex;
  PageController sliderController;

  void setCurrentImageIndex(int newIndex) {
    setState(() {
      currentSlideIndex = newIndex;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    currentSlideIndex = 0;
    sliderController =
        widget.sliderController ?? PageController(initialPage: 0);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    sliderController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void nextPage() {
    sliderController.nextPage(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250), curve: Curves.easeOut);
  }

  void previousPage() {
    sliderController.previousPage(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250), curve: Curves.easeOut);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [
      Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        child: PageView.builder(
          controller: sliderController,
          onPageChanged: (newIndex) {
            setCurrentImageIndex(newIndex);
          },
          itemCount: widget.urls.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return InkWell(
              onTap: widget.openImagePopUp
                  ? () {
                      context.read<NavigationService>().showPopUp(
                          ProductDetailsImagePopUp(urls: widget.urls), context);
                    }
                  : null,
              child: Image.network(
                createImageUrl(widget.urls[index]),

                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                  return LoadImageErrorWidget();
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      if (widget.urls.length > 1) ...[
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          bottom: 10,
          child: CircleIndicators(
            index: currentSlideIndex,
            length: widget.urls.length,
          ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                if (currentSlideIndex < widget.urls.length - 1)
                  IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_left), onPressed: nextPage),
                Expanded(child: Container()),
                if (currentSlideIndex > 0)
                  IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_right), onPressed: previousPage),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ]
    ]);
  }
}
```